# Unexpected type compilation issue when using pipe operations in F#

Tags: f#, linqpad, seq

I am trying to parse a directory of XML files and then select the value of particular attribute if a given node is present. Am not able to understand the reason for the compilation error that the following F# is causing.

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Xml
open System.Xml.XPath
open System.Xml.Linq


let configRootDirectory = @"C:\dir"
let relativeProductDir = @"relDir"

let ExtractConfiguredCalculator (productConfigFile:string) = 
    let xmlNavigator = XPathDocument(productConfigFile).CreateNavigator()
    let node = xmlNavigator.SelectSingleNode(@"Product/SupportedRisk/Risk[@type='PV']") 
    node.GetAttribute("methodology", "")

let configFile = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(configRootDirectory, relativeProductDir), @"*.xml")
                    |> Seq.cast<string>
                    |> Seq.iter(fun configFileName -> ExtractConfiguredCalculator(configFileName))                  
                    |> Seq.filter(fun configuredCalculatorNode -> configuredCalculatorNode != null)
                    |> Seq.iter(fun calculator -> Console.WriteLine(calculator))
```

The above snippet is from the code that I am experimenting with in LinqPad. The error message seen is as below.

```
This expression was expected to have type     unit     but here has type     string
```

**Update** 
Trying to get more f#-ish. Please suggest if something can be improved.

```
let configFile = 
        Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(configRootDirectory, relativeProductDir), @"*.xml")    
        |> Seq.map(fun configFileName -> 
                    let xmlNavigator = XPathDocument(configFileName).CreateNavigator()
                    let node = xmlNavigator.SelectSingleNode(@"Product/SupportedRisk/Risk[@type='PV']")
                    match node with
                    | null -> "PV not configured"
                    | _ -> 
                        let attributeValue = node.GetAttribute("methodology", "")
                        match attributeValue with 
                        | null -> "Calculator not configured"
                        | _ -> attributeValue)
        |> Seq.iter (printfn "%s")
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Oops! missed that! Error message as below:This expression was expected to have type     unit     but here has type     string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to change the first `Seq.iter` to `Seq.map` to return a sequence which is required by the subsequent `Seq.filter`.

I have several comments though:

- `Seq.cast` is redundant since `Directory.GetFiles` returns `string []`.
- When you have `Seq.map` and `Seq.filter` together, you could always replace them by `Seq.choose`.
- `printfn` is a more F#ish way of printing than `Console.WriteLine`.

Here is an improved version:

```
let configFile = 
        Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(configRootDirectory, relativeProductDir), @"*.xml")    
        |> Seq.choose (fun configFileName -> 
                            let config = ExtractConfiguredCalculator(configFileName)
                            if config <> null then Some config else None)
        |> Seq.iter (printfn "%s")
```

Comment: I think you may have typoed (or thinko'd) since there is no `Seq.filter` in the line you quoted. :)

Comment: He could shorten it even more by changing `ExtractConfiguredCalculator` to return `Some string` if the attribute is non-null, otherwise `None`.

Comment: @Daniel: it seems weird with null checking because I expect `GetAttribute` to return empty string if the attribute is not found.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I am trying to learn f# by trying to solve real-life problems, so every suggestion helps.

Comment: I've updated the question with a more f#-ish[or what I understand as more f#-ish version]. Comments/suggestions welcome.

Comment: @Codex: your code is fine. I prefer to return `None` whenever you match with `null` and `Some string` otherwise. In your function, what happens if `attributeValue` is `"Calculator not configured"` by accident?

Answer (score 4):

Your first call to `Seq.iter` should be to `Seq.map`. `ExtractConfiguredCalculator` returns `string` but `Seq.iter` expects a function returning `unit`.